# Variable Scope in Python

Tags: python, maya

I have one question about Python Variable's scope. Here the script i had wrote in Maya using pymel. This readyButton function is inside classA

```
import pymel as pm

def readyButton(self,*args):
    previewMode = pm.button('previewBttn',q=True,bgc=True)
    if previewMode == [0,0,0] :
        pm.button('previewBttn',e=True,bgc =[.608,0,.157],l='On used')
        if (globals().has_key('objList') == False):
            exec('objList = {}') in globals()
```

when i check it, using the same

```
globals().has_key('objList')
```

it return a False value outside of class and True inside the classA. I also need this variable to work with classB, so how can i declare it in globals?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? And what are classA and classB supposed to be?

Comment: `globals()['objList'] = {}` works better than an exec. Or you could just use `global objList`, and define it as `objList = None` at the module level.

Comment: You actually need to change your logic. It seems the first improvement your looking for is declaring `objList = None` in global scope, and then inside `readyButton` you declare `global objList` and instead of checking for the presence of such variable, you check whether it is  `None` and then change it to an empty dictionary.

Comment: That mean i have to create it outside of class :D anyway just see it as a case which i can't solve. Can you give me a explain why this is wrong?

Comment: I agree with Roseman. Your not really describing what you want to do. And thus its really hard to give any satisfactory answer. You don't actually need the thing to be global to use it in classB. As a result all the answers would be pure guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Note thet `has_key()` is deprecated in Python 2.7 in favor of `k in d`

What are the values returned by `'A' in globals()` and `'B' in globals()` , please ?

Comment: it returnTrue in Class and False outside of Class

Comment: @illunara Excuse me, my question was incomplete. First we must know in which modules are declared classes **A** and **B** , please. Are they in the same module ?

Comment: @illunara And what is the object **objList** supposed to be, that is to say where is it supposed to be defined , in which code block (module, function, or class) is it declared ?

Comment: A is the UI Class, and B is another Class that store object attribute (like height,size, number....). The script declare objList as a dict variable in global, it create when a function in class A is call (Only one time), you can see the script i post on top of the post.

Comment: @illunara I don't see any link in your question - By the way, please, put 's' at the ends of verbs at the 3rd person, it is unconfortable not to read ``another Class stores``, ``The script declares``, ``it creates`` etc

Comment: @illunara OK, I understand, you don't pretend there is a link. You mean that you want **objList** to be created thanks to **A().readyButton()** when it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm also new so i don't know how to post a script in the comment.
Class B's name is curveShape()
So whenever i need to call out object's attribute from curveShape() class, i do like this

curveShape(objList['something']).attribute

And yes, When A().ReadyButton() get active the first time, it declares objList variable.

Also, sorry for my English :(

Comment: @illunara Comments are not made to receive scripts, you are right :) You can add something to your answer using the button 'edit' under it

Comment: @illunara Classes are made to be instanciated, not used directly. Aren't there instructions like ``a = A()`` and ``b = curveShape()`` in your code ? - By the way, click on the 'help' under the button **Add Comment** to learn how to format strings in the comments. For example, to bold a string in a comment you surround it with two ``**`` at its left and two ``**`` at its right.

Comment: Thanks, i will look it up later. I just confuse that why in my script, objList only creates inside UI's class, but not in globals

Comment: @illunara Why do you pretend that **objList** is created inside UI's class ? You said that you use the same instruction ``globals().has_key('objList')`` two times, one time outside the class A, one time inside the clas A. But in the two cases, it's the same test that is done: if 'objList' is a key in globals(), not if it is a key in the local ``__dict__``of the class

Comment: @illunara You seem to think that could and should be easy to answer to your question. But you dont' give enough information and explanations. It is necessary to know at which step in the code and how the checking of ``globals().has_key('objList')`` is done inside and outside the class ``A``. At which step is ``readyButton()`` executed ? Did you cretaed an instance of **A** or not, before executing ``readyButton()`` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not good at talking so allow me to summarize it again.
The objList variable, i want to create it OUTSIDE of class A.
Where do i declare it? in the readyButton() function which inside the class A.
And when? In function which create UI part, i had created a button, the first time i click on it, it will trigger the readyButton() function, and variable being created then.
But the problem is, even i though it had been created in global (outside of class A), its in classA. So i can't use it, i just want to ask why did that happen and how should i fix it. Sorry for trouble you :(

Comment: @illunara You must stop to employ the verb 'declare'. In Python there is no declaration of "variables". I employed this term too, in my first comments, here above, as you and mmgp did, but I shouldn't have done so. In Python there's no declaration. By the way there are no variable, too, in the sense of "chunk of memory whose content can change". There are only objects are created at certain times and binded to a name that serves as identifier of the object. People call the identifiers "variables" even in Python, but it's very confusing. It's better to avoid the term "variable" in Python.

Comment: @illunara I think I have understood that the creation of the object **objList** (I continue to employ this name though it is a dictionary.....) is performed only when the function **readyButton()** is triggered , not before or by other means. You say that this triggering is done by pressing a button defined in a ``function which creates UI part``. Where is defined this function ? In ``A`` ?

Comment: @illunara Another imprecise point is how you check the existence of identifier ``'objList'`` in globals(). I suppose you employ an instruction like ``print globals().has_key('objList')``. Where are placed in your code the two instructions to check inside and outside ?

Comment: @illunara The best should be that you post more of your code in order that we see the other class and the instructions by which you check the presence of **objList** in the global namespace

Comment: @illunara would be better if you instead of showing more code would describe what the purpose is. Al the moment is a bit of mystery meat stuff and we don't even know if the question makes sense or not.

Comment: @joojaa I have the same interrogation: I wonder if his question has sense, if he correctly describes the problem. I'd like to clear that point, and if there is really a code that produces the result he described, to understand what detrmines this result. But for the moment, his explanations are like a haze

Comment: @eyquem I don't think code may at the end up helping. Because the question is still so diffuse that it may be even the code makes no sense. We are missing the context. Most likely illuminara just wants to call a partial form the GUI. But can not describe the intent very well.